# println inside forall at Scala

Tags: scala

I have this function in Scala that check if the parameter is a prime number. How do I do to print only the first value of "d" that the function isPrime can divide by "n", inside de "(d => n % d != 0)"? I want to show the first value of "d" that says the "n" is not a prime number.

```
object Collection {
  def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = (2 until n) forall (d => n % d != 0)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("isPrime(7): " + isPrime(7))
    println("isPrime(12): " + isPrime(12))
    println("isPrime(127): " + isPrime(127))
    println("isPrime(254): " + isPrime(254))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
def isPrime(n: Int): Boolean = (2 until n) forall { d =>
  val remainder = n % d
  if (remainder == 0) println("Not prime because of" + d)
  remainder != 0
}
```

Comment: @shivansh-srivastava Thanks for edit, I wasn't paying much attention.. xD

Comment: I was working on the same solution..but you were quite fast :P :D

Comment: thanks, yes, I also did this modification. Now I realized that after => is a function....

Comment: "The insight here is that inside every function with side
effects is a pure function waiting to get out."  -https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

What about this? You can invert question if number is not a prime.

```
def notPrime(n: Int) = (2 until n) find (d => n % d == 0)
```

As a result you get Option[Int] that can be easily checked for true/false.
Negative answer "None" means it's a prime. Positive answer "Some" means it not a prime number.

```
notPrime(7): None
notPrime(12): Some(2)
notPrime(127): None
notPrime(254): Some(2)
```